# WEKA not identifying .ARFF files on M1 Mac

Tags: permissions, weka, apple-m1, arff

I have downloaded the latest version of WEKA on a newer Mac with the M1 chip and am having trouble opening .ARFF files. When I go to open the file, the file is not appearing as an option to open. It is perhaps a problem with permissions? But when I look at the permissions for the app, I am able to read and write. I am not getting an error message of any sort. I can only see the directories and no files.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Many thanks!

I tried uninstalling and making sure I had downloaded the latest version of WEKA and I tried moving the .ARFF file to a new location.